# Nest.js cannot create TestingModule with multiple services

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I tried to build the weatherService testing module but an error happened. WeatherRepo is a provider that goes to db and injected into weatherService. There was a similar problem with HttpModule. Instead of passing HttpModule into imports, I passed HttpService into provides. If I use auto mocking or overriding this works, but not as I expected.

**Here is an error**:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the WeatherRepo (?). Please make sure that the argument WeatherRepository at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
- If WeatherRepository is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If WeatherRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing WeatherRepository */ ]
  })
```

**weather.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, SequelizeModule.forFeature([Weather])],
  controllers: [WeatherController],
  providers: [WeatherService, WeatherRepo],
  exports: [WeatherService],
})
export class WeatherModule {}
```

**weather.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('WeatherService', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const weatherServiceModule: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [WeatherService, ConfigService, WeatherRepo],
      imports: [HttpModule],
    })
      // .overrideProvider(WeatherRepo)
      // .useValue(mockWeatherRepo)
      .compile();

    weatherService = weatherServiceModule.get<WeatherService>(WeatherService);
    weatherRepo = weatherServiceModule.get<WeatherRepo>(WeatherRepo);
    httpService = weatherServiceModule.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
  });

  it('should be defined', async () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(weatherRepo, 'findOrCreate')
      .mockResolvedValue(CreatedWeather(false));
    jest.spyOn(weatherRepo, 'update').mockResolvedValue(2);
    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get').mockResolvedValue({ data: CreateWeather() });
  });
```

**weather.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
    private readonly weatherRepository: WeatherRepo,
  ) {}
}
```

**weather.repo.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class WeatherRepo {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Weather) private weatherModel: typeof Weather) {}
}
```

I wanna supply all required provides/imports/controllers and have the result(ready to work TestingModule). Neither overrides nor auto mocking because I wanna control the behavior of services with spyOn. I have no idea how to solve this. Can someone help?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either provide a mock for the `WeatherRepository` provider (that's the provider injected via `@InjectModel(Weather)` or you need to connect to the database using `SequelizeModule.forRoot()` and then provide the actual provider like you do in the `WeatherModule` using `SequelizeModule.forFeature([Weather])`